# The left socle and right socle of a semiprime ring coincide.

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, socle

Let $R$ be a semiprime ring. Then the right socle and left socle coincide. (The right/left socle for a ring is the sum over all minimal right/left ideals of $R$.) You can assume that the left/right socle are two-sided ideals and that for a semiprime ring $R$ you have the following equivalence:
Let $e=e^2\in R$ : $eR$ is a minimal right ideal iff $eRe$ is a division ring.

I didn't understand the proof in Lambeck's "lectures of rings and modules"(especially the last implication), which goes as follows:

the left socle $S$ of $R$ is $\sum Re$, where $e$ ranges over all idempotents of $R$ for which $eRe$ is a division ring. Similarly, the right socle $S'$ of $R$ is $\sum eR$. Now $S$ is an two-sided ideal, hence $S' \subseteq S$. Similarly $S \subseteq S'$.

Comment: Hi: please [read this advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) , especially the parts about context, and improve your post accordingly. We do not entertain posts that are problem statements only.  Your question may be closed while it is being improved, but feel free to [list it here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today) when you have improved it.

Comment: Thanks for improving the question!

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify what's going on:  the minimal left ideals are precisely of the form $Re$.  This is because of another lemma that is no doubt in your book, that a minimal left ideal $L$ satisfies $L^2=\{0\}$ or $L=Re$ for some idempotent $e$.  The former case is not possible in a semiprime ring, hence we have that all minimal left ideals are of the form $Re$, and so the left socle is the sum of these $Re$'s.

You have that $eR$ is minimal iff $Re$ is minimal, owing to the symmetric nature of the condition "$eRe$ is a division ring."  Let's call the set of such idempotents $X$.

Under the given assumption that $S=\sum_{e\in X}Re$ is an ideal, it must contain $eR$ for every $e\in X$, because it certainly contains every member of $X$.  If $S$ contains every $eR$, then $S$ also contains $\sum_{e\in X} eR=S'$.  *Mutatis mutandi* it also follows $S'\subseteq S$.